# Se vacía la variable de sesión AJAX y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, session

Tengo un sistema en laravel, he usado variable de sesión sin ningún problema, hasta ahora.

Realizó una petición AJAX y en ella agrego datos en una variable de sesión. Esto del lado del PHP funciona sin problema.
Pero cuando vuelvo del AJAX esas variables de sesión no están modificadas.
Si actualizo la pagina tampoco se actualiza la variable de sesión.

En cuanto al código es un put sobre el session. Nada más.

Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Es imposible ver lo que haces si no muestras código.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637277/problem-with-session-variable-laravel-and-ajax

Comment: Tomas . Tengo exactamente el mismo problema. Lo pudiste resolver?
Estoy seguro que viene por el lado del servidor, ya que en 2 entornos funciona perfecto pero en un 3er server, no. En Ajax supuestamente actualizo los valores de las variables de sesión, pero luego resulta que tienen el valor anterior.
Verifico dentro del script de Ajax y cambian su valor, pero sólo dentro de su burbuja, por fuera no se enteran del cambio.